# How to use Firebase JS SDK inside an Iframe that loads an script containing Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting the following error when I try to get Firebase token in my React application.

```
browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: No URL is associated with the caller's document."
code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: No URL is associated with the caller's document. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
```

My application is a Chat widget that should be loaded in any page. When the page includes my javascript file, my application is loaded and creates an Iframe. Inside the Iframe another script is included and this script contains all the Chat widget code and the Firebase library.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://example.net/lib.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      Lib.init({});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

lib.js

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', Components.ID_DIV);
document.body.appendChild(div);

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('id', Components.ID_FRAME);
iframe.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '');
iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
iframe.className = Components.CLASS_BUTTON;
div.appendChild(iframe);

const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
iframeDocument.open();
iframeDocument.write(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://example.net/frame.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body/>
  </html>
`);
iframeDocument.close();
```

frame.js

```
const config = {
  apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
  projectId: '<PROJECT_ID>',
  messagingSenderId: '<SENDER_ID>',
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    console.log(currentToken);
  } else {
    messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
});
```

The Firebase configuration will be provided by the client.
I'm running everything using HTTPS, including the index.html page.
How to make Firebase works in this kind of application?